# How to get a value from a Postgresql table and increment it in PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm making a PHP code that basicaly controls the stock of a company.
I basicaly have three machines, that have a capacity limit:

M001  20
M002  10 ...

My problem is, whenever I insert a new M001 machine using my form, for example, I want to decrease the capacity by 1, so that, in the database I would have:

M001 19

I'm doing this:

```
$query3="SELECT capacidade FROM maquinas2 WHERE maquina='$palavra3'";
$result3=pg_query($query3);
$num=pg_fetch_result($result3,0,'capacidade');

$query = "INSERT INTO maquinas2(codigo,descricao,capacidade,operador,maquina) VALUES    ('$codigo','Montar',$num,'$operador','$palavra1')"; 
$result = pg_query($query); 
$query2 = "UPDATE maquinas2 SET capacidade = capacidade-1 WHERE maquina ='$palavra1' ";
$result2 = pg_query($query2);
```

But it's not working, What can I do?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "but it's not working?" Are you getting an error? is the table being updated with the wrong values?

Comment: @Mureinik       The values from my table get negative (20 turns to -20,and then -19 and so forth)

Comment: Please add some error checking to your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` In addition make use of all of the error reporting functions available for your database.

Comment: You need to think about concurrency here - row locking at least.